# Objective-C: Polymorphism in the case of NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism

I'm a beginner in Objective-C programming and as I was working through an example, I noticed something curious about polymorphism:

```
// I know the message should have been mutableCopy, but this is how I came to find
// this ... anomaly
NSMutableArray *arrayCopy = [self.array copy];
[arrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

This code compiles, however it will crash the app with a message saying arrayCopy does not recognise the message replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:.

My question is, why would this compile in the first place (and it doesn't generate a warning/issue on Analyse)? Given that NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray, how can the assignment of arrayCopy to a returned NSArray be valid?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats the beauty of Obj-C, You can change behaviour at runtime. However this must have warn you about runtime warning with yellow bubble on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing behaviour at runtime"? Is that not what polymorphism provides? In which case all OO languages as well as Objective-C will have this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature for copy is

```
- (id)copy
```

This means it returns a pointer to an Objective-C object but otherwise doesn't provide any type information to the compiler.

This means that the compiler can't warn you about the types being wrong.

Comment: I see... I still find it a little counter intuitive that the assignment does not return any sort of error at runtime. It is effectively saying: arrayCopy is an NSMutableArray but it's not really an NSMutableArray...